# Different types of Core Data Migrations across multiple app versions

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

This might be something simple but would appreciate your patience.

I first launched an application in App Store versioned 1.0 and then for 2.0, I did lightweight migration to core data and pushed the app to store. Now, for 3.0 I need to do non-lightweight/standard migration as I need to change attribute type inside an entity.

My first question is that if I push version 3.0 with non-lightweight migration, will I be able to switch back to lightweight migration for next version 4.0?

If the answer to first question is yes, my second question is if a user is on version 2.0 in above case and did not update to version 3.0 which had non-lightweight migration and when I push version 4.0, will not the lightweight migration in version 4.0 cause an issue to users still on version 2.0?

Thanks!!